# Reduce excess wine sugar

Tags: wine, sugar, fruit-wine

I created 3 liters of pomegranate wine. I think I put excess sugar. Have taken the wine after 24 days.

The wine came out pretty well, but its little sugary, is there a way to decrease the sugar content?

I am planning to create a new batch with less sugar and mix the new wine with old one, will that work?

Any other way to reduce sugar?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can blend old and new wine to create a different wine.

You could pitch in a high attenuating yeast or one with a higher alcohol tolerance. Also, if you transfer to secondary and leave for a couple of weeks, sometimes the small amount of extra DO you pick up in transfer can restart a stalled fermentation and allow it to run to completion.

Do you know what your starting and finishing garivities were?

What yeast are you using?

Did you use concentrate, a kit etc...?

Comment: I dont know what `garivities` are. I am using a yeast which I bought from a baking store, its a dry yeast which I normally use for wine making. I didnt use concentrate or a kit. I used the method and recipe from [here](https://kiranvj.com/blog/random/red-wine-recipe-using-dry-grapes-raisins/). All other batches with dry grapes was great. Pomegranate was new to me.